# I have run truncate table but it is still showing table occupying space?

Tags: mysql, truncate

I have run truncate table but the Heidi SQL is still showing table occupying space.
Database: MYSQL 5.6.26

[image]

I have truncated the con_consumer table but heidi is still showing it taking space. Even other tools like Toad shows it taking up space.
Mysql Engine:Inno DB

Comment: InnoDB or MyISAM?  What does Heidi use to compute the space?

Comment: @RickJames: Edited answer. Please check

Answer (score 4):

Tables with `Engine=InnoDB` take a minimum of one block -- 16KB.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE minsz (x int) ENGINE=InnoDB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.17 sec)

mysql> SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'minsz'\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           Name: minsz
         Engine: InnoDB
        Version: 10
     Row_format: Compact
           Rows: 0
 Avg_row_length: 0
    Data_length: 16384   <-- Brand new table, still empty, yet 16KB
Max_data_length: 0
   Index_length: 0
...
```

If I had added an secondary index (not `PRIMARY KEY`), `Index_length` would also be one block.  (Heidi would probably show 32KiB.)

I might add a hundred rows before the table and/or its index expands beyond 16KB.

Comment: How does it answer my question? I have run truncate table but it is still showing data in table. Is it some my sql bug?

Comment: It is not showing _data_ in the table.  It is showing that a table has some overhead.  Even a table with no data takes 16KB.

Comment: Surely you are not worried about the disk space -- it is insignificant compared to the total of 116.1MiB.  And, if you want "number of rows", that display does not give you that.  And there are less obvious anomalies -- a size could go _up_ when you _decrease_ the number of rows, or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

The statistics are cached.  To force them to update use the 'ANALYZE TABLE' query

```
ANALYZE TABLE um_comsumer.con_consumer_detail;
```

Then refresh the view in your mysql frontend (heidisql in your case).

In HeidiSQL you can right click on the database, select 'maintenance'.  In the dialog that opens, in the operations dropdown select 'analyze' and click 'execute'.

Answer (score 0):

Answer #1 is not understanding the question.  Original post is asking about the con_consumer table, not the one he has highlighted in the screen shot.   I just confirmed answer #2. "ANALYZE TABLE tablename" works.   I had same problem and that fixed it.  I'm on MySQL 8.0.

Don't forget to hit REFRESH in Heidi after the ANALYZE.